# Tikhonov regularized least-squares with unit simplex constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, constraints, quadratic-programming

First, I got this $\ell_2$ norm problem, which is easy to solve

$$w_0 = \arg\min_⁡ \|  −_ \|_2^2+  \lambda \|\|_2^2 \tag{1}$$

where $X$ is a matrix and $\lambda$ is a fixed scalar. Then, I added the following constraints

$$∈[0,1], \qquad \thinspace \sum_ _i =1 \tag{2}$$

At first I found this optimization problem similar to **fmincon** function of matlab (reference [here](https://kr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)), but I keep getting poor results (significant higher error than results in Eq(1)).

I already try with other matlab build-in functions such as  lsqlin, lsqnonneg but all return bad results (err = $\|X*w_o - _ \|_2^2 $) such as

Eq2-fmincon: 75596.826, Eq2-lsqlin: 386.2777, Eq2-lsnonneg:311.5511, Eq1: 0.0019292

Is there any suggestion on how to solve this problem? 
Thank you for your time.

---

My matlab code for fmincon are follow

```
gamma = 1; 
fun = @(w) ((norm(X * w  - xc, 2))^2 + gamma * (norm(w, 2))^2);                    
w0  = rand(size(X, 2), 1); %w0 = w0./sum(w0); 
A   = [];                   b   = []; 
Aeq = ones(1, size(X, 2));  beq = 1; 
lb  = zeros(size(X, 2), 1); ub  = ones(size(X, 2), 1); 
w1  = fmincon(fun,w0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub) ;
w2  = lsqlin(X, xc, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub); 
w3  = lsqnonneg(X, xc);
w4  = pinv(X' * X + gamma * eye(size(X,2))) *X' * xc;

tmp1 = norm(X * w1 - xc, 2);     tmp2 = norm(X * w2 - xc, 2); 
tmp3 = norm(X * w3 - xc, 2);     tmp4 = norm(X * w4 - xc, 2); 

display(['Eq2-fmincon: ' num2str(tmp1) ', Eq2-lsqlin: ' num2str(tmp2) ', Eq2-lsnonneg:' ...
            num2str(tmp3) ', Eq1: ' num2str(tmp4)]);
```

Comment: Fmincon is a valid approach. What algorithm did you use? Did it converge? Why do you think there are $w$ that satisfy your constraints but give lower errors?

Comment: Thank you. I did use fmincon but got "Solver stopped prematurely" with large error. I added matlab script to my question.

Comment: Your nonlcon-code runs fine on my random data set. It might help if you provide gradient information, and if you ensure that the starting point is not too close to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I initiate w0 via random number so it should not be close to 0 or 1. The gradient for fmincon is not stable. You can find it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/x95cio4150jj4a0/fminconGrad.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry. with "provide" I meant to provide it to fmincon; see "include gradient" at https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html It is not clear to me what your graph shows. The gradient for your problem is a vector.

Comment: yes I plot gradient with this function [w1,fval,exitflag,output,lambda,grad]  = fmincon(fun,w0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub) ;

Comment: I believe there would be better solution since the difference in error two problem is too large. It about Eq2-fmincon: 75596.826, Eq2-lsqlin: 386.2777, Eq2-lsnonneg:311.5511, while it is only Eq1: 0.0019292 for the first optimization problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [regularized least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularized_least_squares) (RLS) problem subject to the standard $(n-1)$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). We have the following **quadratic program** (QP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2 + \lambda \| \mathrm x \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & 1_n^{\top} \mathrm x = 1\\ & \mathrm x \geq \mathrm 0_n\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} &  \mathrm x^{\top} \left( \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A + \lambda \mathrm I_n \right) \mathrm x - 2 \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \text{subject to} & 1_n^{\top} \mathrm x = 1\\ & \mathrm x \geq \mathrm 0_n\end{array}$$

Do note that if $\lambda < 0$, then the QP may be **non-convex**.

In MATLAB, one can use function [quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) to solve this QP.

Comment: A thousand thanks :D, i will check the matlab code soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by [Projected Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method#Subgradient-projection_.26_bundle_methods) since the [projection onto the Unit Simplex](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/blob/master/Optimization/BallProjection/BallProjection.pdf) is known.

The Code:

```
vX = pinv(mA) * vB;

mAA = mA.' * mA;
mAb = mA.' * vB;

for ii = 1:numIterations
    stepSize = stepSizeBase / sqrt(ii);
    vG = (mAA * vX) - mAb + (2 * paramLambda * vX);
    vX = vX - (stepSize * vG);
    vX = ProjectSimplex(vX, simplexRadius, stopThr);
end

objVal = (0.5 * sum((mA * vX - vB) .^ 2)) + (paramLambda * sum(vX .^ 2));

disp([' ']);
disp(['Projected Gradient Solution Summary']);
disp(['The Optimal Value Is Given By - ', num2str(objVal)]);
disp(['The Optimal Argument Is Given By - [ ', num2str(vX.'), ' ]']);
disp([' ']);
```

The full code (Validated by CVX) is in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q1983030 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q1983030).

You can even accelerate this using [Nesterov / FISTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Fast_gradient_methods) to get really fast and efficient algorithm.